# Check if the decimal digits is equal to .9 using javascript

Tags: javascript

Just want to ask if how to detect numbers in decimal places using javascript?

```
var totalpages = {{$photos->totalphotoCount}} / {{$photos->photoCount}};
if(totalpages === to something like .9 in the decimals)
{
write a code here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(totalpages.toString().match(/.*\.9/)) {
  ...
}
```

if it does not match, it would return null

Comment: You are welcome, please, mark it as right answer too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex's but if you need more advanced check you can add a helper method like this

```
// count specifies how many decimals you want to return
function getDecimals(number, count) {
    var nString = number.toString();
    var decStartIndex = nString.indexOf(".") + 1;
    nString = nString.slice(decStartIndex, decStartIndex + count); 
    return Number(nString);
}

function myFunction() {
    var num = 123.2381456;
    var dec1 = getDecimals(num, 1); // returns 2
    var dec1 = getDecimals(num, 0); // returns 0
    var dec1 = getDecimals(num, 5); // returns 23814
}
```